# problem with using count & sum to get data from 2 tables

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions, mysql-error-1242

I have two tables applications and leads

application table

```
submitDate | fName | lName
2010-11-15    joe    smith
2010-11-16    joe    smith
2010-11-15    joe    smith
```

Leads table

```
submitDate | click | state
2010-11-15    1      ca
2010-11-16    1      ca
2010-11-16    1      ca
2010-11-15    1      ca
2010-11-15    1      ca
2010-11-15    1      ca
2010-11-15    1      ca
2010-11-15    1      ca
```

I want a query to return this result

```
submitDate | application | clicks | percent
2010-11-15    2            6          33%
2010-11-16    1            2          50%
```

I tried the following

```
SELECT `submitDate` , count(`submitDate`)  AS 'comp',(select sum(`click`) from `leads`

 WHERE `submitDate` between '2010-11-15' AND '2010-11-16' group by `submitDate`)as

 'clicks'  from `applications` WHERE `submitDate` between '2010-11-15' AND

 '2010-11-16' group by `submitDate`
```

this return an error

```
#1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row
```

and tried the following

```
SELECT `leads`.`submitDate` , count(`leads`.`submitDate`) 
 AS 'application',sum(`click`) as 'clicks'  
from `applications`,`leads` WHERE `leads`.`submitDate` between 
'2010-11-15' AND '2010-11-16' group by `leads`.`submitDate`
```

this return the following result

```
submitDate | application | clicks
2010-11-15    60           60
2010-11-16    6            6
```

leads table have 22 columns / 20 = 2010-11-15 and 2 2010-11-16 
the application table as same as the above table

I'm sorry for the long explination but to be clear

any idea?

and about add new field percent that devided applications/leads
SO the result will have 4 columns

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select d.date, coalesce(a.count, 0) as applications, coalesce(b.count, 0) as clicks
from 
(
    select date from applications
    union
    select date from leads
) d
left outer join (
    select date, count(*) as count
    from applications 
    group by date
) a on d.date = a.date
left outer join (
    select date, count(*) as count
    from leads
    group by date
) b on d.date = b.date
```

Comment: how to  add new field percent that devided applications/leads SO the result will have 4 columns?
I edited the table result above

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.submitdate
, count(a.submitdate)
, (select sum(clicks) from leads where submitdate = a.submitdate) 
, count(a.submitdate)/(select sum(clicks) from leads where submitdate = a.submitdate) percent
from applications a
group by a.submitdate;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.submitDate,
  (SELECT count(*) FROM applications GROUP BY submitDate) as App,
  (SELECT count(*) FROM leads        GROUP BY submitDate) as Leads
```

Only caveat is to include a bunch of `where`'s as  necessary, including in the subqueries.

Comment: Those subqueries would return more than one row and make the query fail.

Comment: @Martin Schapendonk: The subqueries will return exactly the same number of rows as the original select, by definition of the select distinct.

Comment: The subqueries do not contain the DISTINCT keywords. When you use an inline query, it should return at most one record. Both inline queries in your answer return as many records as there are submitDate's in the underlying tables.